# Split formatted time range expression by first space and hyphen

Tags: php, regex, split, text-extraction, text-parsing

I want to split this string to 3 array element.

```
$string = 'MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM';
```

Output:

```
array[0] = MW
array[1] = 01:00 PM
array[2] = 02:30 PM
```

Help me with the regex expression that will extract that string to an array.

```
^[a-zA-Z\d-_]+$
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How do other strings look like?

Answer (score 4):

You can [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) at spaces and [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) hyphen if there is a [digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) ahead by use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$arr = preg_split('/ +-? *(?=\d)/', $str);
```

[See demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/b9ZD08/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$str = "MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM";

$matches = [];

preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+PM)\s+\-\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+PM)$/",$str,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM
    [1] => MW
    [2] => 01:00 PM
    [3] => 02:30 PM
)
```

**Explanation:**

- We have to match the string from the start to the end. So, we use `^` and `$` at the corners of our regex.
- `([a-zA-Z]+)\s+` is used to match alphabetic characters along with 1 more extra spaces.
- `\d{1,2}` is used to match 1 or 2 digits of time(like `1`, `01`, `11` etc)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WVNdEh/1)

Answer (score 0):

This works too (but is longer):

```
$str = "MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM";
preg_match('/([A-Z]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}) - ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2})/', $str, $match);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($match, true) . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM
    [1] => MW
    [2] => 01:00 PM
    [3] => 02:30 PM
)
```

Comment: I suppose for this "splitting" task, I don't prefer `preg_match()` because it creates a 4-element array instead of the desired 3-element array.  `preg_split()` and `sscanf()` accommodate the 3-element requirement more directly.

Answer (score 0):

While [you can split on sequences of one or more spaces and/or hyphens which are followed by a digit](https://3v4l.org/NcoOK), regex is not your only option here. This is a text extraction task, not a text validation task.  Looks how concise `sscanf()` can be.

When you have a string with predictable format and no optional characters, often enough `sscanf()` can be helpful.  `%s` (in `scanf()` and `printf()` functions) acts to match visible characters (not spaces).  The `%` marks the start of a placeholder, the (optional) next digit specifies how many characters to match, then the character class / negated character class defines what characters will qualify as a match.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VE2lU))

```
$string = 'MW 01:00 PM - 02:30 PM';
var_export(
    sscanf($string, '%s %8[^-] - %8[^-]')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'MW',
  1 => '01:00 PM',
  2 => '02:30 PM',
)
```

---

As an extension of requirements, if it is desirable to isolate each variable component as a separate element in the output array, see the following implementation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RQMv3))

```
var_export(
    sscanf($string, '%s %2s:%s %s - %2s:%s %s')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'MW',
  1 => '01',
  2 => '00',
  3 => 'PM',
  4 => '02',
  5 => '30',
  6 => 'PM',
)
```

--

To cast the hour and minute substrings as integers, use `%d`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KbbO3))

```
var_export(
    sscanf($string, '%s %d:%d %s - %d:%d %s')
);
```